# How to properly run a shell script in C++

Tags: c++, shell, sh

I'm trying to do this in my .cpp file:

```
system("/home/user/workspace/script.sh");
```

I just want to open it, get it running on its shell and then forget about it. My solution so far is just doing this:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    system("/home/user/workspace/script.sh");
}
```

And it works. The thing is that I'm not sure if that is properly done, but even if it is, I am getting some warnings that I don't want to see in my output:

```
(gnome-terminal:8105): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.

(gnome-terminal:8105): Vte-2.90-WARNING **: No se pueden convertir caracteres de UTF-8 a actual.

(gnome-terminal:8105): Vte-2.90-WARNING **: No se pueden convertir caracteres de UTF-8 a actual.

(gnome-terminal:8105): Vte-2.90-WARNING **: No se pueden convertir caracteres de UTF-8 a actual.
Unhandled value type TerminalEncoding of pspec encoding
```

Any advices? Thank you so much.

Comment: `system("/home/user/workspace/script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1");` will get rid of the output, but for anything more complicated I would use http://pstreams.sf.net/

Comment: you can use the shellexecute functions for that see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx even if the msdn is talking about executables, you can use it for scripts, pictures or whatever, it will open the *.exe linked to the files e.g. *.txt files with editor.exe and it's possible to start the script as admin this way

Comment: @Nitro.de I doubt so, this obviously doesn't run on a Windows-OS, and it wasn't in question anyhow.

Comment: you're right it's my fault i should read the whole text next time^^

Comment: what about the execv function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `system()` function causes running a separate process using the current shell (this is what interprets the string argument), and this process behaves exactly as if you ran it from the shell manually (that is, it will spit its stdout and stderr streams as usual). You can do two things:

- redirect output somewhere when running from `system()` (as hinted in the comment)
- use subprocess channel redirection - `fork()`, then "make the process switch itself into a command" using `execl()`. Between `fork()` and `execl()` you can `close()` unwanted streams (1 = stdout, 2 = stderr), and if this caused problems in running the secondary process when it tried to write to a closed file, you can `dup()` to them a newly `open()`-ed descriptor to a "/dev/null" file

Actually the second solution is the same as the first one in the final result - the difference is that second one does not involve shell to execute your process, but it's more complicated.